# ReactJS falsely claims a string is an object and refuses to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Setup and environment: App is created with create-react-app, contained in App.js, and run using npm start at the command line.

Obligatory source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

async function getRemoteData() {
  var result = [];
  const response = await fetch('some.site.that.returns.json'); // not the actual URL although you get the idea
  const json = await response.json();
  for (const entry of json.entry) {
    result.push(json.fullUrl);
    console.log(json.fullUrl);
  }
  console.log("String representation");
  console.log(result.toString());
  // Following commented string used to test ReactJS functionality
  // return "";
  return result.toString(); 
}

// minimalist self-explanatory class that dumps a message to the browser
class Message extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{this.props.text}</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

function App() {
  return ReactDOM.render(<Message text={getRemoteData()} />, document.getElementById('root'));
}

export default App;
```

This only produces an unhelpful, untraceable error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h2 (at App.js:23)
    in div (at App.js:22)
    in Message (at App.js:31)

First, getRemoteData should not be return a Promise at all. It should return a string - painfully obvious from the return statement.  I'm using kudlajz's answer in [Fetch: set variable with fetch response and return from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869197/fetch-set-variable-with-fetch-response-and-return-from-function) - using await to fix the asynchronous aspect and then returning the underlying value.

Next, I set up getRemoteData to return an empty string on purpose - test ReactJS. Same result If it's claiming an empty string is an invalid object, that's a serious problem. Next, this provides absolutely no info on what's going wrong. Any ideas how to get this to work? Why is an Object (rather than a string) being returned at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getRemoteData` is an **`async`** function. It returns a Promise, which is an object.

To deal with asynchronous data, you need to store the result in the state and use that instead.

See also the React FAQ: [AJAX and APIs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

Comment: How do I get it to automatically resolve then with a minimum of fuss?

Comment: Put the data in the state. Have the render method check the state to see if the data is there. You might want to display a loading spinner if it isn't. The FAQ has an example.

Comment: Tested the instructions in the FAQ and it worked. Enjoy your upvote and answer accept.